# Deleting records with foreign keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have a little question about deleting records with foreign keys.
The problem is that, at the start I thought it is really helpful using foreign keys but when i used them it is really problematic for me. 
For example:
I created Two tables:

```
Pizza: id, name, price
Order: id_Pizza (Foreign Key), address, telephone, date
```

All the time a client makes an order there is created record with ID of pizza ordered.
Suppose that i have had 2000 orders of pizza Margherita (id=1), so i have 2000 records with id_Pizza = 1. 
Now I need to delete margherita from my menu because I no longer want to sell that type of pizza but i cant, because it is used as Foreign Key in Table Orders.

How to manage that problem?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the orders that had that type of pizza?  Do you want to keep them?  Do you want to still be able to tell that the order contained a Margherita pizza?  If so, you could consider adding some type of `ShowOnMenu` flag to your pizza table... and then set it to false for the pizza that you want to hide.  That way you can still report on past orders while not showing the Margherita pizza on your current menu.

Comment: Really helpful advice by Michael. I'd do the same thing. I think you can accept it as an answer.

Comment: I would definitely do what Michael said.  The only other option is to delete the orders from your order table that have the id of 1.  But this just causes extra work and you will lose that information about what pizzas the customers used to order

Comment: Yea, Michael I think i will do as you adviced. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Never delete the row--instead introduce an `active bit not null` column and display on the menu only the table entries that have `active=1`.

Darn, i'm hungry now...

Comment: Yes, i'll do it in that way, same as Michael proposed but thank You too.

Comment: ahh -- just saw his comment.